# Haar measure on isomorphic subgroups

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $G$ be an abelian locally compact Hausdorff group endowed with a chosen Haar measure $\mu$. Moreover, let $H,N$ be subgroups of $G$ where $N$ is discrete. Then we have the isomorphic quotient groups
$$\frac{(H+N)}{N}\cong\frac{H}{H\cap N}.$$ If we put the natural counting measure on the discrete subgroups, then we get a unique induced measure on the quotient. Now I wonder whether the groups in the isomorphism have the same volume under the canonical measures? Or maybe a better formulation is, whether the pushforward measure induced by the canonical measure on the left hand side coincides with the canonical measure on the right hand side?

Edit: We assume that the restricted measure on $H$ is nonzero, and therefore a Haar measure. On $N$ we denote the measure by $\lambda$, and on $H\cap N$ the restricted measure by $\lambda_{H}$. On $G$ we have the measure $\mu$, and on the quotient $G/N$ the measure $\nu_{N}$. The unique induced measure on $G/(H\cap N)$ is denoted by $\nu_{H}$. We want to show that $\nu_{N}((H+N)/N) = \nu_{H}(H/(H\cap N))$ (if it is true).

I guess that if this it true, one needs the quotient integral formula. But I dont exactly see how to obtain it here.
$$\nu_{N}((H+N)/N)=\int_{G/N}\chi_{(H+N)/N}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{N}(x)$$
$$\nu_{H}((H/(H\cap N))=\int_{G/(H\cap N)}\chi_{H/(H\cap N)}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{H}(x),$$
where the integrands are the characteristic funtions. The reason why I think the quotient integral formula is needed, is that the measure on $H\cap N$ is just the restriction of the measure on $N$. And therefore you might get a nice equality when you can write the integral
$$\int_{G/N}\chi_{(H+N)/N}(x)\mathrm{d}\nu_{N}(x) = \int_{G/N}\int_{N}f(yn)\mathrm{d}\lambda\mathrm{d}\nu_{N}(yN),$$
for some integrable $f$.

Comment: Haar measure is unique up to a scaling factor, thus it remains to see if the induced measure in the RHS is also invariant under (left) translation

Comment: @Masacroso Suppose that this is known, (since I guess that it is not always true, for instance when $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}$, then the induced measure on $H$ is the zero measure). Then how does this isomorphism make sure that this scalar is equal to one?

Comment: As you observe, the notion of "induced measure" on a subgroup will give the $0$ measure, unless the subgroup is open. This can happen in $p$-adic (or other totally-disconnected) situations, but not so much in archimedean (real Lie group) situations. Perhaps you can clarify what you really need?

Comment: @paulgarrett The moment that made me think that this was a property, is the calculation of the volume of $A_{K}/K$ as given in https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/786/notes.pdf Prop 5.5. Here they give an isomorphism between $A_{K}/K$ and $A_{K,S_{\infty}}/\mathcal{O}_{K}$, and just calculate the volume of the latter one, without giving an argument why the two quotients have the same volume under the isomorphism. This isomorphism can be proven by the second isomorphism theorem. Therefore I thought that maybe such a property was true. So my main purpose, is to understand this specific compution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not exactly what you're wanting, but a true thing that I can tell you. :)

For example, given a unimodular topological group $G$ and unimodular subgroup $H$ (discrete, for example), there is a small theorem that asserts that any two out of the three (positive, regular, Borel) measures on $G$, $H$, and $H\backslash G$ uniquely determine a measure on the third, so that the natural identity holds, for $f\in C^o_c(G)$,
$$
\int_G f \;=\; \int_{H\backslash G} \Big(\int_H f\Big)
$$
If one wants, one can insert more notation to be explicit, but nothing would really be gained. In fact, I like this decluttered version...

EDIT: To compare the adelic quotient $\mathbb A/K$ and purely archimedean quotient $\mathbb A_\infty/\mathfrak o$, use the fact that $\mathbb A_\infty\times \prod_v\mathfrak o_v$ is *open* in $\mathbb A$, so $\mathbb A_\infty/\mathfrak o\times \prod_v \mathfrak o_v$ is open in the adelic quotient. In fact, it is in bijection with it. Thus, specifying the (Haar) measure on $\prod_v \mathfrak o_v$ completely determines the comparison of the adelic quotient's measure and the archimedean quotient's measure.

Comment: I indeed know about this fact, and think that this should be applied in a proper way to obtain the desired result used in the computation of the volume of $A_{K}/K$. The measures in the numerators (denominators) of $A_{K}/K$ and $A_{K,S_{\infty}}/\mathcal{O}_{K}$ are related by just being restrictions of the measure. And I guess, the unicity of the quotient measure by the above should gives us that the volume of $A_{K}/K$ equals the volume of $A_{K,S_{\infty}}$, when applied properly. But I don't see how.

Comment: Ah, I see. @Math, I'll get back to you later on this.

Comment: I think Im missing a crucial, probably trivial, point here.  To clarify my confussion, consider the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. Then we have an obvious isomorphism between both intervals. But when considering the volumes with respect to the Lebesgue measure, they differ by a factor $2$. In other words, our bijection actually does affect the volume. And I don't see, under the given arguments, how this won't be the case when considering the adelic quotient.

Comment: Well, _groups_ are more rigid things than sets... But, yes, even then, circles are all isomorphic as topological groups, but do come in different sizes/diameters, and we may or may not want to give the total mass $1$, or, maybe, instead, $2\pi$ times radius. In brief, _some_ specification of maps between objects is needed to specify measures... For that matter, on adele quotients, we could gives $\prod_v \mathfrak o_v$ measure $1$, which would give an incompatible measure... There _are_ moving parts, but they _can_ be lined up with some effort. :)